# Marcar campos duplicados numa tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Tenho uma tabela no meu banco de dados e gostaria de marcar as ocorrências onde determinado código se repete. Lembrando que esse campo código não se trata de uma chave primária.

Exemplo:

```
Data        Código    Repetição   Status    ...
25/2/2014   138863    ok          C96       ...
25/2/2014   387707    ok          C96       ...
25/2/2014   387707    nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   387707    nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   387707    nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   ok          C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   nok         C96       ...
25/2/2014   1845141   nok         C96       ...
```

Alguem tem idéia de como posso criar a coluna repetição com a lógica acima (primeira ocorrência, marcar como `ok`, nas demais `nok`) utilizando alguma query?

No momento estou utilizando essa tabela num Banco de Dados em Access.

Comment: Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY e conte a quantidade de repetições. A cláusula HAVING cont(*) > 1 pode ajuda-lo a filtrar apenas as repetições.

Comment: Você pode colocar na pergunta as tabelas de origem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível com uma subquery que retorna um elemento por código.

Vamos a um exemplo com a estrutura abaixo:

```sql
create table teste (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    codigo int,
    repeticao  varchar(10)
);
```

A seguinte query retorna um `ok` apenas uma vez por código:

```sql
select
  codigo,
  case
    when id = (
      select min(t2.id)
      from teste t2
      where t2.codigo = teste.codigo
    )
    then 'ok'
    else 'nok'
  end repeticao
from teste
```

### [Veja o sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b447/4)

---

Em forma de update, você pode fazer assim:

```sql
UPDATE teste
SET repeticao = 
    case
        when id = (
            select min(t2.id)
            from (select * from teste) t2
            where t2.codigo = teste.codigo
        )
        then 'ok'
        else 'nok'
    end;
```

Note que o MySQL não permite selecionar a própria tabela em um subselect no comando `UPDATE`, mas o trecho `(select * from teste)` é um *workaround* para burlar essa limitação.

### [Veja o sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce67/1)

Comment: Ótima resposta @utliz. Precisei fazer uma alteração para funcionar no Access pois o mesmo não suporta case. 
```SELECT Dados_Exportar.codigo, IIf(id=(select min(d2.id) from Dados_Exportar d2 where d2.codigo = Dados_Exportar.codigo),'ok','nok') AS rep FROM Dados_Exportar;```